# Data about Power Transformer Failure for predictive maintenance

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I'm having trouble finding data about this subject, the data banks that I've explored were of little use. Essentially what would be useful is several data about transformer usage, external conditions, maintenance, etc. Does anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to hook few sensors on the power transformers & monitor their values ver time.
Also you need some alogorithms working in the system to inform you on possible failures.
Also you can apply various formulas for the key paramaters like overloading,Gas PPM LOL,Paper degradation etc
Regards
Sanjaya Srivastava
seaasipl@gmail.com
+919004520982